# Cargar una imagen en una tabla utilizando JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-web-api

Estoy haciendo un WEB API soy nuevo en esto, ocupo mostrar la imagen que almacene en la bd, esta imagen también la tengo almacenada en mi Servidor. Ahora no puedo acceder a ella desde mi cliente, no aparece, aparece como cuando no carga la imagen, en mi tabla aparecen todos los datos menos el de la imagen. El atributo de bd que se encarga de la imagen, se llama imageCategory

El metodo que estoy usando para listar los datos es el siguiente

```
    $.get("URL DEL GET")
    .done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $.each(response, function (id, value) {
            $("<tr>").append(
                $("<td>").text(value.idCategory),
                $("<td>").text(value.Category),
                $("<td>").append($("<img>").addClass("img-thumbnail").attr({ "src": "src/letter-k.png" })),
                $("<td>").append(
                    $("<button>").data("id", value.idCategory).addClass("btn btn-outline-warning me-2 btn-sm editar bi bi-pencil-fill").text("").attr({ "type": "button" }),
                    $("<button>").data("id", value.idCategory).addClass("btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm eliminar bi bi-trash-fill").text("").attr({ "type": "button" })
                )
            ).appendTo(".table");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, (y aunque probablemente ya lo sabes, pero no viene mal comentarlo) ten en cuenta que la imagen no viene de la base de datos, en la base de datos solo se almacena el "path" al fichero.

La imagen primero intenta visualizarla sin el `$.get`, haz algo como:

```
<img src="src/letter-k.png" />
```

Debes poder visualizar la imagen, caso contrario el PATH es incorrecto o la imagen no existe.
también puedes probar a escribir en el navegador
`localhost/src/letter-k.png`, deberías visualizar la imagen.

Porque no veo ningún error en tu `JS`.

Answer (score 0):

hola muchas gracias me ayudo mucho

```javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?= site_url('/quinto') ?>",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(response) {
     $.each(response, function(id, value) {
      $("<tr>").append(
       $("<td>").text(value.nombre),
       $("<td>").text(value.ap),
       $("<td>").text(value.am),
       $("<td>").append($("<img>").addClass("add").attr({
        "src": "<?= base_url() ?>/public/fotos/3.png"
       })),
       $("<td>").append(
        $("<button>").data("id", value.id).addClass("btn btn-outline-warning me-2 btn-sm editar bi bi-pencil-fill").text("").attr({
         "type": "button"
        }),
        $("<button>").data("id", value.id).addClass("btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm eliminar bi bi-trash-fill").text("").attr({
         "type": "button"
        })
       )
      ).appendTo("#tablas");
     });
    }
   });
  })
```

Comment: En lugar de escribir saludos y agradecimientos (¿a quién?), explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código, _y cómo responde a la pregunta_. Otras personas más adelante verán tu respuesta y puede que no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.